# Everytime I try to login it shows me authentication failed or createUserWithEmail:onComplete I just cant get it to function

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to login and register since the past 2 days. I just can't help myself, please. It always shows me authentication failed and `createUserWithEmail:onComplete`, it shows me the statements together and sometimes individually.I don't know what to do. Somebody, please solve this for me. I am so tired, I have my project submission and I have been stuck on this.

Register:

```
 package com.example.kiit.questionme2;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

 import java.util.Objects;


public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
    btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity3.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Activity3.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Activity3.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Login code

```
 package com.example.kiit.questionme2;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
  import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

  import java.util.Objects;


public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
    btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity3.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Activity3.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Activity3.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: Error message as in? There is no error in the build or it compile or debug. I am sorry I am new to this

Comment: When I try to register it does show in the toast with that message that Authenticationfailed.com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException.A network error(.such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occured.

Comment: I'm considering that you have already added `google-services.json` file in the project. Right?

Comment: Yes I have added it and the dependencies

Comment: on which device you are testing?

Comment: On the emulator Pixel 2

Comment: Try it on real device once. The reason is google play services is not updated as per the dependencies.

Comment: I tried it crashes when I do that

Comment: But I did update the google play services on the emulator

Comment: still, you will get an actual crash reason on the console when you use it on the real device. Am very much sure.

Comment: It shows me createUserWithEmail:onComplete:false and authentication failed at once when i click register and the login activity wont open when i press the login button on the screen it just blinks